# how to deal with ssh keys when reformatting computers

Tags: ssh

I'm about to reformat my ubuntu desktop and I need ssh keys to access my servers on the cloud. (DigitalOcean)

what would be the best way to go about this?

I was thinking I'd just copy my `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` files on over, but is there are better way?

Comment: This seems like a non-problem in the context of having a backup of your computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create new keys and update digitalocean
2. Keep a copy of the keys and move them over

I would do 2